# Grid not resizing when child's visibility is changed

Tags: xamarin, grid, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin app with a Grid, where there is a Label and an Entry. 
When I change the Entry’s text, I want the Label to be visible, and if it is empty, it shall not show the Label.

I have created a demo-app to verify, that it does not have anything to do with my code. But the following code also fails

```
MainPage = new ContentPage
{
   Content = new Grid
   {
      ColumnDefinitions = new ColumnDefinitionCollection
      {
         new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(1,GridUnitType.Auto) },
         new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) }
      }
   }
};

Label label;
Entry entry;
Grid mainGrid = ((Grid)((ContentPage)MainPage).Content);
mainGrid.Add(btnDelete = new MR.Gestures.StackLayout
   {
      Children = {
         new ExtendedLabel { Style = Styles.LargeLabelIcon, Text = "\ue634", TextColor = Color.Black }
      },
      WidthRequest = 50
   }, 0, 0);
mainGrid.Children.Add(label = new Label { Text = "TEST", IsVisible = false }, 0, 0);
mainGrid.Children.Add(entry = new Entry { }, 1, 0);
entry.TextChanged += (sender, arg) => label.IsVisible = entry.Text.Length > 0;
```

Does anybody have an idea of how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is what your are trying to achieve:

```
MainPage = new ContentPage
{
    Content = new Grid
    {
        ColumnDefinitions = new ColumnDefinitionCollection
          {
            new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(1,GridUnitType.Auto) },
            new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) }
          }
    }
};

Label label;
Entry entry;
Grid mainGrid = ((Grid)((ContentPage)MainPage).Content);
mainGrid.Children.Add(label = new Label { 
    Text = "TEST", 
    IsVisible = false,
    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start,
}, 0, 0);
mainGrid.Children.Add(entry = new Entry { 
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
    BackgroundColor = Color.Black,
    TextColor = Color.White
}, 1, 0);
entry.TextChanged += (sender, arg) => label.IsVisible = entry.Text.Length > 0;
```

I have added vertical and horizontal options to the controllers.

Comment: It still does not show the Label :( The Grid does not resize the column, so there are space for the Label

Comment: Is this the correct behavior? https://media.giphy.com/media/jpAMKvwazudOM/giphy.gif

Comment: Yes, it is exactly, what I am looking for

Comment: I have created the .gif with the code I have posted above btw I am running the iOS version.

Comment: Can you get the same behaviour with MR.Gestures.StackLayout?

Comment: Ohh I am not sure, I suppose No I am using a normal Xamarin Forms Grid

Comment: I am also using a normal Grid, but instead of a Button, I am using a StackLayout (as I understand, it is not possible to set the Font for a Button)

Comment: If you want to change the font of a button you need to create a Custom Renderer, But what does this has to do with an Entry and a Label?

Comment: The Label shall have the same function as a Button (that's why I have choosen MR.Gestures.StackLayout

Answer (score 0):

I just had a very similar issue.  After the text on my child component was changed, it would be cut-off.

The problem turned out to be that you can't mix a `ColumnDefinition` of `*` on the grid with a `HorizontalOptions` on the child. Having both seems to break something.  Replacing it with `HorizontalTextAlignment` fixed it for me.

Maybe this will help someone else someday.